# How to get album art from last.fm Android

Tags: android, audio-player, last.fm, albumart, android-music-player

I'm making an Music player for Android, I want to provide feature for users to get album art of a song from last.fm.

I've got my API key too. Just need help for retrieving the image from Last.fm.

Any help in getting the image url would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S : For more info about my music player, check the link below
https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/115046175816530349000

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an solution check below

Add the below AsyncTask loader

```
public class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String albumArtUrl = null;
        try {
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(urls[0]); // getting XML from URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Size = " + e.getAttribute("size") + " = " + parser.getElementValue(e));
                if(e.getAttribute("size").contentEquals("medium")){
                    albumArtUrl = parser.getElementValue(e);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return albumArtUrl;
    }
}
```

Call it as followed :

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/");
stringBuilder.append("?method=album.getinfo");
stringBuilder.append("&api_key=");
stringBuilder.append("YOUR_LAST_FM_API_KEY");
stringBuilder.append("&artist=" + URLEncoder.encode("ARTIST_NAME_HERE", "UTF-8"));
stringBuilder.append("&album=" + URLEncoder.encode("ALBUM_NAME_HERE", "UTF-8"));
url = new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(stringBuilder.toString()).get();
```

You need 2 classes :
1. XmlParser
2. DocElement
Both of which will be available in link below.
[Xml parsing tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: I have heard that we cannot use last.fm api to download cover arts for public use..isn't it ?

Comment: I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @NandanKaushik this is true, in fact I emailed last.fm support who confirmed this, so all the apps on google play using last.fm for album art shouldn't be doing so - unless they consent, however I asked for consent and was told that I shouldn't be using for any app.

Comment: @Mark Do you know why they have made all apis for public use ?

Comment: @NandanKaushik From their website - `The Agreement covers only Your use of Last.fm Data. You must not sub-license the Last.fm Data to others.` - so they are public, but for 'personal' use only, sharing any data is considered sub-license.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Last.fm Web Services docs for `album.getInfo`: http://www.last.fm/api/show/album.getInfo
Here is a sample response, from which you can easily see how to get cover art image url:

```
<album>
  <name>Believe</name>
  <artist>Cher</artist>
  <id>2026126</id>
  <mbid>61bf0388-b8a9-48f4-81d1-7eb02706dfb0</mbid>
  <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Cher/Believe</url>
  <releasedate>6 Apr 1999, 00:00</releasedate>
  <image size="small">...</image>
  <image size="medium">...</image>
  <image size="large">...</image>
  <listeners>47602</listeners>
  <playcount>212991</playcount>
  <toptags>
    <tag>
      <name>pop</name>
      <url>http://www.last.fm/tag/pop</url>
    </tag>
    ...
  </toptags>
  <tracks>
    <track rank="1">
      <name>Believe</name>
      <duration>239</duration>
      <mbid/>
      <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Cher/_/Believe</url>
      <streamable fulltrack="0">1</streamable>
      <artist>
        <name>Cher</name>
        <mbid>bfcc6d75-a6a5-4bc6-8282-47aec8531818</mbid>
        <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Cher</url>
      </artist>
    </track>
    ...
  </tracks>
</album>
```

Comment: I figured it out in Android.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Which service did you use? Why don't you share your solution here on SO? :-)

Comment: I just completed it. On the way to add solution here